# How to use Caret and dollar in regex Expression?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to learn regex but i'm struck at my first code only.
I read that caret(^) and dollar($) is used to match at the beginning and end of the test respectively. But i'm getting hard time to figure out what is wrong with my code.

```
  public class Test1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String letterA="cat will die";
            String pattern="[^cat]";
            System.out.println(letterA.matches(pattern));
            String pattern1="^(cat)";
            System.out.println(letterA.matches(pattern1));
            String letterB="Lending your cat";
            String pattern3="[cat$]";
            System.out.println(letterB.matches(pattern3));
            String pattern4="cat$";
            System.out.println(letterB.matches(pattern4));
        }

    }
```

Every syso is giving me Output `false`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Caret and dollar are [Anchors](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html) that just tells if your pattern should look for start(Caret) and end(Dollar) of the line.

Also, inside of brackets, this syntax is changed. if you start with [^...] it means a negation, that you are trying to match any char that is not after the caret. And $ inside the brackets just tells the engine that you are looking for a match for the $ char.

Also, matches in java only return true if you match your entire string.

Having this things in mind, lets pass for each of your cases and see why they are not matching:

---

```
String letterA="cat will die";
String pattern="[^cat]";
```

This regex is looking for a single char that is not 'c' or 'a' or 't'. A string like "f" would return true for this one.

---

```
System.out.println(letterA.matches(pattern));
String pattern1="^(cat)";
```

The () are [capturing groups](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html), they do nothing in you case for matching. 
^ just tells you will look for the match in the start of the string, and your regex is trying to match the string "cat". This is the only possible match that returns true for this case.

---

```
String letterB="Lending your cat";
String pattern3="[cat$]";
```

This is just trying to match single char strings that would be either 'c' or 'a' or 't' or '$'

and finally :

```
String pattern4="cat$";
```

Is just trying to match the exactly string 'cat' (anchored to the end, but it really doesn't make a difference).

So, back to your problem, you need to use something like the .* operator that matches any number of chars like:

- `^cat.*$` (if you want a string that starts with *cat*)
- `^.*cat$` (if you want a string that ends with *cat*)
- `^.*cat.*$` (if you want any string that has the text *cat* in it)

Comment: Good explanation on what he did wrong on setting regex

Comment: "This is the only possible match that would return true for this case". for the line you wrote is even returning me false

Comment: Better edit that part then. Any idea why that would happen? does match ignore the capturing groups and refer to the chars? Is it trying to match (cat) ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but `(cat)` is the same as `cat` except that if you use a `Matcher m` you can use `m.group(1)` on the first one.

Comment: Well, it actually worked here, for me returned true, so im reediting back to previous

Comment: I'm getting confused.  `"cat will die"` will match the patterns `cat` or `(cat)` or `^(cat)` if you use `find()` on a `Matcher`, but will not match if you use `matches()`.

Comment: Matches must match the entire string to return true, find must find a match in the string

Comment: @HomeAlone, which line is returning false to you? in that part i meant "cat".matches("^(cat)") would return true, is that what you tried?

Comment: syso for `String pattern1="^(cat)";`

Comment: Don't know whats wrong for you. For me "cat".matches("^(cat)")  keeps returning true everytime I run...

Comment: @HomeAlone - You are using `"cat will die".matches("^cat")` and this answer says use `"cat".matches("^(cat)")`

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear in that part buddy, but its exactly what @TheLostMind said. I just stated that for your pattern "^cat", the only input string that would match is "cat" not a single char more. So "cat will die" will return false.

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs on `String.matches`. The expression must match fully. For example, try the pattern `.*cat.*`

Also, `^` used in `[]` means to negate, so `[^cat]` reads to a regex engine - "not c, or a, or t". Not sure if you knew, so just in case...

Comment: To be precise, `^` inside `[]` means to negate only if it's right after `[`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in Java `matches()` method matches the entire string. So, using `^` and `$` is *unnecessary*.

You have to use something like this : `letterA.matches("cat.*")` to match a string which strats with `"cat"`.

Boundary Matcher : matches *"word boundaries"* denoted by `"\\b"`

example String : "catterpillar will die";

`letterA.matches("cat.*")` // will return true

`letterA.matches("\\bcat\\b.*")`//will return false

Comment: What the use of Boundary Matchers then in java ?

Answer (score 0):

That is eample using regex for partial matching.

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;


public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Console console = System.console();
        String letterA="cat will die";

            String spattern=".*cat.*";
            System.out.println(letterA.matches(spattern));

            Pattern pattern = 
            Pattern.compile(console.readLine("%nEnter your regex: "));
            Matcher matcher = 
            pattern.matcher(console.readLine("Enter input string to search: "));

            System.out.println(matcher.find());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to java docs

> `public boolean matches()` Attempts to match the entire region against
>   the pattern.
>
> If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the
>   start, end, and group methods.
>
> Returns:
>       `true` if, and only if, the entire region sequence matches this matcher's pattern

Now Since every one has already mentioned the flaws in your regex. i will not write about about it. But let me give some insight about caret(^) and dollars($)

Reading ^$ and ^

1. `^` literally matches if the line has beginning of line.
   `Effectively Speaking meaningless ! Why because every line has a beginning, everyline will match- even the lines that are empty !

see the below code

```
String letterA="";//i'm not writing anything because matches attempt to match entire region
        String pattern="^";
        System.out.println(letterA.matches(pattern));
```

It will Give you Output `True`

So does every line has ending too

```
String letterA="";
        String pattern="$";
        System.out.println(letterA.matches(pattern));
```

this will also give you output `true`